# Creating durable subscriber using Polling Consumer in camel

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am trying to create a durable subscriber using polling consumer.
The URI is correct as same uri is working when used in camel route and durable subscriber is correctly created.
For some reason PollingConsumer is not able to create durable subscriber and instead creates normal subscriber.

Is it not possible to create durable subscribers using polling consumer?

```
public class OutQWaitingProcesser implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Endpoint endpoint = exchange.getContext().getEndpoint("jms:topic:response?clientId=5&durableSubscriptionName=abcd");
        PollingConsumer consumer = endpoint.createPollingConsumer();
        consumer.start();
        Exchange exchange2 = consumer.receive();
        String body = exchange2.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        exchange.getIn().setBody(body);
        consumer.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Camel JmsPollingConsumer is based on Spring JMSTemplate which doesn't support to set the durableSubscription option.

Comment: That's correct. Thanks for telling me this. Is there any other way to do this in java code using camel. I want to wait for messages on a queue in camel route before sending response back to a web service, I do not want to create a new route with queue as a producer endpoint.

Comment: You can do some receiving work in the processor or bean https://camel.apache.org/bean method. But I'm afraid you need to use JMS API to create a durable subscriber consumer yourself and receive the message there. BTW, it is not a good practice to block the thread of the web service if you have lots of user want to access the service.

Comment: Thanks Willem, you are correct, this one is for few cases only which would be rarely used. Normally our webservcie is async.